# I am trying to enforce a naming convention on checked in file for a pre merge check in BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

What I want to do is allow this to be merged to bitbucket.

PREFIX_MyFileName.sql
PREFIX_YourFileName.sql

but exclude

AnythingElse.sql

Basicly I want to enforce a naming convention.
I was trying to use Pre-Recieve Server Side Hooks:

- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#server-side-hooks
  Is there an easier way?

I tried the serverside hooks but I could not get my spring class to load correctly.